# Extraer datos a través de SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

Buenos días amigos tengo un problema a la hora de llamar datos de dos tablas las cuales se relacionan por un numero de orden, ya que están creadas para guardar una formula. El problema es, que cuando las llamo por SQL, me muestra todos los datos por separado y quisiera mostrar juntos todos los que tengan el mismo numero de orden.

Les agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Este es mi código de SQL:

```
public function get_DproductoB(){

             $conectar= parent::conexion();
           
             $sql="select
p.id_Dproducto,p.fecha_Dproducto,p.numero_Dproducto,p.productoc,p.categoria,
p.moneda,p.subtotal,p.total,p.estado,p.id_producto,c.id_detalle_Dproducto,
c.numero_Dproducto,c.productoc,c.id_Mprima,c.materiales,c.unidadm,c.moneda,
c.precio,c.cantidad,c.importe,c.fecha_Dproducto,c.estado

          from Dproducto as p, detalle_Dproducto as c 
          where 
          p.fecha_Dproducto
          =c.fecha_Dproducto
          and
          p.numero_Dproducto
          =c.numero_Dproducto
          and
          p.productoc
          =c.productoc
          and
          p.moneda
          =c.moneda
          and
          p.estado
          =c.estado
        


          ;";
             
             $sql=$conectar->prepare($sql);

             $sql->execute();

             return $resultado= $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        
        }
```

[image: esta es la manera en que me los muestra]

Comment: podes poner un ejemplo de lo que recibis ahora y como queres que salga?

Comment: Puedes explicar cuál es la salida deseada. ¿Qúe signfica todo junto?. Pon algunas filas de Dproducto, algunas filas de detalle_Dproducto y el resultado esperado.

Comment: Y yo añadiría, ¿Qué campo es el numero de orden?

Comment: el campo en que se relacionan es numero_Dproducto

Comment: quisiera que al hacer el select el relacione todos los datos que tienen el mismo numero_Dproducto, por el momento muestra todos los datos que estan en las tablas pero por separados aun que tengan el mismo numero_Dproducto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes "agrupar" los registros por ese campo de "número" para que los que tengan el mismo número no te salgan repetidos:

**Ejemplo:**

```
<?php
     public function get_DproductoB(){

          $conectar= parent::conexion();
          $sql="select
          p.id_Dproducto,p.fecha_Dproducto,p.numero_Dproducto,p.productoc,p.categoria,
          p.moneda,p.subtotal,p.total,p.estado,p.id_producto,c.id_detalle_Dproducto,
          c.numero_Dproducto,c.productoc,c.id_Mprima,c.materiales,c.unidadm,c.moneda,
          c.precio,c.cantidad,c.importe,c.fecha_Dproducto,c.estado

          from Dproducto as p, detalle_Dproducto as c 
          where 
          p.fecha_Dproducto
          =c.fecha_Dproducto
          and
          p.numero_Dproducto
          =c.numero_Dproducto
          and
          p.productoc
          =c.productoc
          and
          p.moneda
          =c.moneda
          and
          p.estado
          =c.estado
          GROUP BY p.numero_Dproducto
          ";
          $sql=$conectar->prepare($sql);

          $sql->execute();

          return $resultado= $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    }
?>
```

Comment: gracias amigo si me funciono, te lo agradezco mucho.